# Question about extending a function whose counter-image is a quotient space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $W$ a closed subspace of $H$ and $\mathcal{T}: H\rightarrow H/W$ a well defined linear bounded operator. My question is under what conditions can I find a bounded $T:H \rightarrow H$ such that $q\circ T = \mathcal{T}$, where $q:H \rightarrow H/W$ is the canonical map.

I am currently completely lost and out of ideas, any tip will be appreciated.

Comment: It should be  $q\circ T$ instead $T\circ q.$ The quotient space $H/W$ is isometrically isomorphic to $W^\perp.$

Comment: I see.... Thanks! I also edited the question with your remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ denote the orthogonal projection onto $W^\perp.$ Then $I-P$ is the orthogonal projection onto $W.$
Moreover there holds $$\|[v]\|=\|Pv\|\qquad (*)$$ Indeed, we have $v=(I-P)v+Pv,$ hence $[v]=[Pv],$ which implies $\|[v]\|=\|[Pv]\|\le \|Pv\|.$ On the other hand for any $w\in W$ we get
$$\|v+w\|^2=\|Pv+(I-P)v+w\|^2\ge \|Pv\|^2$$
Thus $\|[v]\|\ge \|Pv\|.$

Consider the operator $U:H/W\to H$ given by
$U([v])=Pv.$ The operator is well defined due to $(*).$ The same formula implies that $U$ is a linear isometry.
Observe that $q\circ U=I_{H/W}.$ Indeed
$$(q\circ U)([v])=q(Pv)=[Pv]=[v]$$
Let $T=U\circ\cal{T}.$ Then $$q\circ T=q\circ U\circ \cal{T}=\cal{T}$$